# MySQL database needs a flush tables every now and again. Can I script something to resolve this?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm having a problem that I hope someone can help me out with.

Currently, every now and again we receive an error when our scripts (Java and PHP) try to connect to the localhost mysql database.

Host 'myhost' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'.

This issue appears to mainly occur in the early hours of the morning.  After alot of searching to figure out why this may be occuring I have finally come to the conclusion that it may be due to the fact our hosting company runs their backup processes around this time.  My theory is that during this backup process (this is also our busiest period) we end up using up all our connections and so this error occurs.

I have talked to our hosts about changing the times these backups occur but they have stated that this is not possible and that is simply the times the backups start to ensure they are finished in time for the day (Even though we have informed them our critical period is at the precise times the backups occur).

The things I have connecting to the server are:

1. PHP website
2. PHP files run using chron jobs
3. A couple of java applications to run as socket listeners that listen for incoming port connections and uses the mysql database for checking user credentials and checking outstanding messages.

We typically have anywhere from 300 - 600 socket connections open at any one time and the average activity on these are about 1-3 request per second.

I have also installed monit and munin with some mysql plugins on the server in the hope they may help auto resolve this issue however these do not see to resolve the issue.

My questions are:

1. Is there something I can do to auto poll the mysql database so if this occurs I can auto flush the database to clear
2. Is this potentially even related to the server backup.  It seems a coincidence it happens 95% of the time during the period the backups occur.
3. Any other ideas that may help.  Links to other websites, or questions I could put to our host to help out.

We are currently running on a **PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny9** server with Apache.

If any more information is required to help, please let me know.  Thanks.

UPDATE:
I am operating on a shared virtual host and am pretty sure I close my website connections as I have this code in my database class

```
  function __destruct() {
    @mysql_close($this->link);
  }
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not using persistant connections via my PHP script as I connect to the db the @mysql_connect command.

UPDATE:
So I changed the max_connections limit from 100 - 200 and I changed the mysql.persistant variable from On to Off in php.ini.  Now for two nights running the server has gone done and mainly the connection to the mySql database.  I have one 1GB of RAM on the server but it never seems to get close to that.  Also looking at my munin logs the connections never seem to hit the 200 mark and yet I get errors in my log files something like

1. SQLException: Too many connections
2. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
3. SQLException: null,  message from server: "Can't create a new thread (errno 12); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug.
4. SQLState :: SQLException: HY000, VendorError :: SQLException: 1135

Comment: Change your hosting company and full-stop.

Comment: Really, is changing my hosting company the best idea?  Since alot of our customers are connecting to our socket via an IP, changing hosts would be a bit of a pain?  Salman A, what do you mean close connections explicitly?  At the bottom of each PHP file I include a footer that calls a close.  And in my java i only keep the connection open for each query.

Comment: If you suffer at a specific time only. You could of course just cron the command to run - however, as a question, if you're using mysql as a credentials verifier, perhaps you should consider getting a proper demon written to run which makes only a few connections / reuses etc.

Comment: @BugFinder  Sorry, I don't just use the database for credentials.  That is one part of the Java socket solution but it also runs other queries on parts of the database.  As for cron'n the job.  Have you got any examples of how to cron a flush database command, or perhaps point in the right direction?

Comment: Could be that your running on a shared MySQL container. If this is the case the whole container will only have a limited number of allowed connections. 

If this is the case, and you are 100% sure that you're closing all connections as each script terminates (even though it would be much, much better to handle this in a data abstraction layer and close the connection in "__destruct" when the object falls out of scope). 

I suggest it could be your hosting companies backup routine that is monopolising the container. Ask then to investigate.

Comment: @Skidoosh  thanks skidoosh.  I do call @mysql_close($this->link) in my db __destruct class already so I'm trusting that is closing the connections from my web site.  And for my java stuff I've followed the standard methods for closing connections so pretty confident that is ok.  and yes, I am on a shared virtual host.

Comment: @dreza Had the same issue on another shared host a few years back. Switching your hosting may not be a bad idea overall, but you could just get some MySQL only hosting elsewhere which would remedy your issue also (and is quite a simple migration process to boot).

Comment: Are you able to debug whether it is the PHP or Java programs taking up the connections ? You could be leaking connections somewhere. It also sounds like you should use a database connection pool. There's no reason to have 100 connections to the db (other than allow for easy programming )

Comment: @nos.  I didn't think I was leaking connections but I've looked into connection pooling and will try implementing that on my java module and see if that helps.

Comment: @dreza: Your question now is more than a year old. How did you solve your issue? Or weren't you able to solve it and you still have got the errors in your logs?

Comment: @hakre no completely.  However I ended up implementing connection pooling which seems to have limited the problem to some degree as I have not seen the issue in a while.  I also did things like increased RAM and increased the max connections a bit.

Comment: @dreza: Can you leave that as an answer and accept it? I think this would be helpful for future users of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been suggestion I post an answer to this question although I never really got it sorted.

In the end I ended up implementing a Java connection pooling class which enabled me to share connections whilst maintaining a upper limit on the number of max connections I wanted.  It was also suggested I increase the RAM and increase the number of max connections.  I did both these things although they were just bandaids to the problem.  We also ended up moving hosting providers as the ones we were with were not very co-ooperative.

After these minor implementations I haven't noticed this issue occur for at least 8 months which is good enough for me.

Other suggestions over time have to also implement a Thread pooling facility, however current demand does not require this need.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a similar problem with out large ecommerce installation using MySQL as a backend. I'd suggest you alter the "max_connections" setting of the MySQL instance, then (if necessary) alter the number of file descriptors using "ulimit" before starting MySQL (we use "ulimit -n 32768" in /etc/init.d/mysql).

Comment: I've tried increasing the max_connections from 100 to 200.  My server currently has 1GB of memory so hopefully that will be enough.  I'm not sure how to change the file descriptors limit just yet so will see how this goes for now.